# How do I view a long C++ output to console (Only displaying end portion)

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, console, codeblocks

I am running codeblocks on Linux Mint 17 and I have not had any issues until now. I am running a relatively long sequence of output and my terminal will only show the last 500 lines of output to Console (terminal). I am needing to view the beginnining portion of the sequence and I would like to know if there are any settings I could change within my OS or codeblocks itself to adjust the amount of output that is printed to console. Perhaps there is a way to save the console output to file (without coding for filestream)? Thank you! I appreciate your help greatly!

EDIT: 
 I forgot to mention I am using C++ and the console I am using is Linux Mint default terminal.

Comment: It depends on what console you are using. Many come with a configuration menu option. **ADD:** Alternatively you could redirect the output to a file: `./myprog > myfile.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use less command in linux.

Ex : ./a.out (executable file) | less

In windows you have "more" command.

as like above linux command, you can pipe your output to "more" command and see full result.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the terminal you could just ouput it to a text file like this:

```
./execution_file > text_file.out
```

The executable file should be in the same folder as the cpp file, but if you cant find it you could use:

```
g++ -o codefile.cpp executionfile
```